# How to make TouchableOpacity wrap its content when nested inside parent that has flex = 1

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity

I know that as default TouchableOpacity always has width as wrap-content. But I place it inside a View that has flex: 1. TouchableOpacity's width become match-parent/take the full width of the screen.

```
<View style={ {flex:1} }>
   <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>I'm button</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

The question is how could I make the TouchableOpacity wrap-content while nested inside a View like that.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use position: "absolute" style for the TouchableOpacity

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
   <TouchableOpacity style={{position: "absolute" }}>
      <Text>I'm button</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

You can also use
alignSelf:'flex-start' can use center or flex-end as well.

Comment: I've tried your recommendation, the TouchableOpacity works as expected but does position: "absolute" make the TouchableOpacity jumps to the top-left corner of the screen? But thanks (y)

Comment: Yes i missed that point, you can use alignSelf:'flex-start' can use center or flex-end as well.

Answer (score 0):

you can style `TouchableOpacity` like this so that `TouchableOpacity` will have it's own style

```
               <View style={ {flex:1} }>
                  <TouchableOpacity style={{width:'80%',height:'20%'}}>
                      <Text>I'm button</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
```

Comment: This is actually not what I want to achieve. The TouchableOpacity width should increase/decrease follow the width of its child.